# Using iconv to convert from UTF-16BE to UTF-8 without BOM

Tags: text, utf-8, utf-16, iconv

I'm trying to convert a UTF-16BE encoded file (byte order mark: 0xFE 0xFF) to UTF-8 using iconv like so:

```
iconv -f UTF-16BE -t UTF-8 myfile.txt
```

The resulting output, however, has the UTF-8 byte order mark (0xEF 0xBB 0xBF) and that is not what I need. Is there a way to tell iconv (or is there an equivalent encoding) to *not* put a BOM in the UTF-8 result?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Experiment shows that indicating `UTF-16` rather than `UTF-16BE` does what you want:

```
iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 myfile.txt
```

Comment: Works but still curious why it works that way. My experiments also lead me this way but thanks for trying it out.